# Reduce database restore time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups

I have a database backup file of 4.78 GB. When I restore it on any machine, it takes a lot of time (15 - 20 mins to be precise) to get restored. The mdf file of the database is of 5.64 GB and ldf is of 100mb. There are lots of tables and lots of data in the database. Is there any way by which I can reduce the time taken to restore the backup file?

Comment: These are full backups and only a single file to restore, and not a chain?

Answer (score 1):

Restoring speed depends on various factors like

- Processor Speed
- Your Harddisk reading and writing speed.

Upgrading these factors should also increase the Database restore time

Comment: my processor is Intel Core i3-3220 3.30 GHZ, 64 bit Windows 8 OS, 4 GB RAM. Is this configuration not good enough to give me decent performance? Do I need to upgrade to much higher config?